# Flutter Awesome Notifications sound not working

Tags: flutter, notifications

The notification sound not working with android emulators greater or equal to API 26. But it working fine with API less or equal to 25.

this is the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final LocalNotificationService notificationService = LocalNotificationService();

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  notificationService.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Awesome Notifications Flutter Test',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => notificationService.showNotification(
            title: "title",
            body: "notification body",),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LocalNotificationService {
  LocalNotificationService();

  final _localNotificationService = AwesomeNotifications();

  initialize() {
    _localNotificationService.initialize(
      'resource://drawable/res_custom_icon',
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'channel_key',
          channelName: 'channel name',
          channelDescription: 'channel description',
          defaultColor: Colors.green,
          playSound: true,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          enableVibration: true,
          enableLights: true,
          ledColor: Colors.white,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void showNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) {
    _localNotificationService.createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: _createUniqueId(),
        channelKey: 'channel_key',
        title: title,
        body: body,
        customSound: 'resource://raw/res_custom_sound',
      ),
    );
  }

  int _createUniqueId() {
    return DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.remainder(100000);
  }
}
```

`pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: untitled
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0-271.4.beta <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  awesome_notifications: ^0.6.21

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

android block from `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.untitled"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

the output of `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.3.0-0.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1889], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.11.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: In android notification channels decide how the sound will be for the notification, when a channel is created with a certain sound it cannot be changed. So create a new Notification Channel with the sound you want and make sure you are using the correct channel

Comment: @Fadel it's a new project, and the sound was set from the beginning. However I created a new channel but still not working with API 26+.

Comment: @MAlhamry, did you found some solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
channelKey: 'sound_channel'
```